# Web service Client error

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, jboss

I have created a Web service and it is running on tomcat server
and my web service client is also on tomcat server.
I have two web server running on my machine tomcat and jboss
when i deploy webservice and web service client in tomcat it work perfect.
But when I deploy same webservice in jboss both clients for tomcat and for jboss web service are stoped working. it give me following error.

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:522)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:398)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:337)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:266)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)

root cause

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:850)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:779)
    org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:103)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:374)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:337)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:266)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)

root cause

java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
    java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    javax.xml.soap.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:55)
    javax.xml.soap.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:133)
    javax.xml.soap.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:166)
    javax.xml.soap.SAAJMetaFactory.getInstance(SAAJMetaFactory.java:75)
    javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory.newInstance(MessageFactory.java:144)
    com.sun.xml.ws.api.SOAPVersion.<init>(SOAPVersion.java:178)
    com.sun.xml.ws.api.SOAPVersion.<clinit>(SOAPVersion.java:83)
    com.sun.xml.ws.api.BindingID.<clinit>(BindingID.java:318)
    com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parseBinding(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:424)
    com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parseWSDL(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:321)
    com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:146)
    com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.parseWSDL(WSServiceDelegate.java:263)
    com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:226)
    com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:174)
    com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:104)
    javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:56)
    com.dnb.discovery.searchservice.SearchServiceService.<init>(SearchServiceService.java:57)
    org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:83)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:374)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:337)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:266)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)

root cause

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.LocalStrings != com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.LocalStrings
    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:314)
    com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.SAAJMetaFactoryImpl.<clinit>(SAAJMetaFactoryImpl.java:71)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
    java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    javax.xml.soap.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:55)
    javax.xml.soap.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:133)
    javax.xml.soap.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:166)
    javax.xml.soap.SAAJMetaFactory.getInstance(SAAJMetaFactory.java:75)
    javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory.newInstance(MessageFactory.java:144)
    com.sun.xml.ws.api.SOAPVersion.<init>(SOAPVersion.java:178)
    com.sun.xml.ws.api.SOAPVersion.<clinit>(SOAPVersion.java:83)
    com.sun.xml.ws.api.BindingID.<clinit>(BindingID.java:318)
    com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parseBinding(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:424)
    com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parseWSDL(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:321)
    com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:146)
    com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.parseWSDL(WSServiceDelegate.java:263)
    com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:226)
    com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:174)
    com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:104)
    javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:56)
    com.dnb.discovery.searchservice.SearchServiceService.<init>(SearchServiceService.java:57)
    org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:83)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:374)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:337)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:266)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
```

Comment: show your webservice code, from the stacktrace it seems it is not ablel to create an instance of your class